# Memory consumption on an iteration script

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, php

I have a script written in PHP and the same script written in Javascript.
It iterates a million times and on each time strips a string into an array and assigns the first array item into a new variable.

The PHP is:

```
class First
{
public function Iterate()
{
    $count = 1000000; 
    $test_string = '';
    $test_array = '';
    $first_word = '';
    for($i=1; $i <= $count; $i++){
        $test_string = 'This is a test string';
        //could use explode but no explode in js
        $test_array = split(" ", $test_string);
        $first_word = $test_array[0];
    }
}
}
$first = new First();
$first->Iterate();
```

And the Javascript is:

```
function First() {
this.Iterate = function() {
    count = 1000000;
    test_string = '';
    test_array = '';
    first_word = '';
    for(var i=1;i <= count; i++){
                    test_string = 'This is a test string';
                    test_array = test_string.split(" ");
                    first_word = test_array[0];
    }
}
}
first = new First();
first.Iterate();
```

I run PHP with PHP-CLI 5.3.10 and the Javascript with node v0.6.12.

For PHP I use 'memory_get_usage()' and for Javascript I use 'process.memoryUsage()'. I run them at the start of the script, then at the end, then minus end with start and finally convert the number of bytes into mb.

The PHP uses 0.00065 mb of memory whereas Javascript uses 0.25 mb however PHP takes 4 secs and Javascript takes 0.71 secs. I have run the results on 2 different machines.

Does anybody know why the Javascript memory usage would be so much higher than the PHP's (despite the fact that the Javascript is executed so much faster)?

The only explanation I could come up with was the V8's nature to use Hidden classes improves speed but increases memory consumption.

Comment: just a note: the scripts are not the same. the vars inside php function are private, in js are globals.

Comment: Your test examples aren't as similar as they could be. In the JavaScript You should apply your Iterate method as part of First's prototype object... that way you aren't recreating the method on each execution (which is closer to how php behaves).

Comment: @pebbl thanks. Something like First.prototype.Iterate = function()

Comment: Yep. Rather than what you have do :- `function First(){}; First.prototype.Iterate = function() { ... }` obviously the `...` should be replaced with the Iterate function body code (I don't have the space to fit here). By doing this it means the `Iterate` function is only created once... I'd be surprised if this didn't lower your js mem usage, but it does depend on what optimisations the modern browsers now do (they are getting complicated beasts).

Comment: It's likely not a size/speed tradeoff but just an incidental, meaningless thing. Nobody particularly cares about memory usage at this level on a general purpose PC, and certainly nobody tries to optimize such small numbers to make them insignificantly smaller. If I had to guess, I'd guess that javascript is initializing something that's running unrelated code (such as garbage collection) as a result of this code running and you're seeing its memory usage.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz would garbage collection not result in more CPU time and less memory (have read the V8 reclaims objects in memory which are no longer required)? This is kind of why I was running these tests in the first place to see results/benchmarks for myself.

Comment: @CraigTaub: Actually *doing* the collection might take more CPU, but initializing it won't. It can be as sample as allocating an array of hash buckets and zeroing them because they're empty.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz appreciated David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are very different execution environments.

In the case of PHP, the source is converted into a series of opcodes - kind of like p-code, while v8 uses a JIT compiler. The latter will tend to be more profilgate with memory usage, however I suspect the biggest difference between the 2 for memory usage is due to different policies for garbage collection:

```
$test_array = split(" ", $test_string);
```

and

```
test_array = test_string.split(" ");
```

create an object on the stack which is discarded at the end of each iteration.

Neither provide much access to controlling run time memory usage.

Comment: thanks, going to amend the local var so its different for each iteration and see what that produces as the Stack will increase properly now.